# Sorting Time(hours) in R

Tags: r, time

I have the below dataset from excel and the numbers indicate hours, how can I convert this into a flexible dataset where I can arrange(order) my dataset any way I want to.

I have tried something below using `lubridate` but that doesnt let me arrange desc or asc.

```
Category   Time1    Time2
1        A 0:30:00 24:00:00
2        B 1:00:00 23:23:00
3        C 2:30:00 23:00:59
4        D 3:00:00 45:00:00

> dput(t1)
structure(list(Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Time1 = c("0:30:00", 
"1:00:00", "2:30:00", "3:00:00"), Time2 = c("24:00:00", "23:23:00", 
"23:00:59", "45:00:00"), hr1 = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0), year = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 
1, 2, 3), minute = c(30, 0, 30, 0), class = structure("Period", package = "lubridate")), 
    hr2 = structure(c(0, 0, 59, 0), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0), month = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(24, 23, 23, 45), minute = c(0, 
    23, 0, 0), class = structure("Period", package = "lubridate"))), .Names = c("Category", 
"Time1", "Time2", "hr1", "hr2"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Rcode**

```
t1<-read.csv("time1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(lubridate)
t1$hr1<-hms(t1$Time1)
t1$hr2<-hms(t1$Time2)
```

**Output**

```
Category   Time1    Time2       hr1        hr2
1        A 0:30:00 24:00:00    30M 0S  24H 0M 0S
2        B 1:00:00 23:23:00  1H 0M 0S 23H 23M 0S
3        C 2:30:00 23:00:59 2H 30M 0S 23H 0M 59S
4        D 3:00:00 45:00:00  3H 0M 0S  45H 0M 0S
```

Comment: What `Time1` and `Time2` stand for? How do you have 45 hours?

Comment: `Time1 `and `Time2` are just some random variable for hours, 45 is a number hours and not exactly time, i think i should change the column name.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ?difftime function that you are looking for.
But since you coded hours as greater than 24 this will not work.

A dirty workaround is to code everything in seconds and go from there:

Function to convert a vector of hours[1],minutes[2],seconds[3] character all to seconds:

```
convS<-function(x) {
    x<-as.numeric(x)
    seconds<-c(3600,60,1)
    x<-x*seconds
    sum(x)
  }
```

apply that function to your splitted character vectors with the 2 time variables and put output in two new variables with elapsed time in seconds:

```
t1$Time1Secs<-unlist(lapply(strsplit(t1$Time1,":"),convS))
t1$Time2Secs<-unlist(lapply(strsplit(t1$Time2,":"),convS))
```

So now you have numeric variables with time difference in seconds, to order your dataset anyway you want.